# How to add an additional 'property' to each column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, properties, dataframe

I am having a data frame with several columns looking like this (but with many more columns):

```
> df <- data.frame(Var1 = 1:10, Var2 = 11:20, Var3 = 21:30, Var4 = 31:40)
> df
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1     1   11   21   31
2     2   12   22   32
3     3   13   23   33
4     4   14   24   34
5     5   15   25   35
6     6   16   26   36
7     7   17   27   37
8     8   18   28   38
9     9   19   29   39
10   10   20   30   40
```

For some columns I would like to do some operations. How can I adress only those columns all at once instead of addressing each column at its own?

Is there a possibility to give each column a "property" or "label" (sorry I do not now the correct term)?

Let's say Var1 and Var2 have "property" = "a", where as Var3 and Var4 have "property" = "b".

Then I would be able to do something like

```
if (property of column = "a"){column with property a * 2}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a vector or something where this property is stored?   If you need to do some operation on multiple columns, try `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate_each(funs(.*2), Var1:Var2)`

Comment: Why not put those columns, on which you would like to do some operations, in another vector, which you then can use for column subsetting.

Comment: There multiple questions in your request ... first you can put `attributes` to your `data.frame` like `attributes(df)=list(Var1='a')`. Then take your attributes and update the wanted column.

Answer (score 2):

> For some columns I would like to do some operations. How can I adress
>   only those columns all at once instead of addressing each column at
>   its own?

Why not put those columns in another vector, which you then can use for column subsetting like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = 1:10, Var2 = 11:20, Var3 = 21:30, Var4 = 31:40)
cols <- c("Var1", "Var2")
df[, cols] <- sapply(df[, cols], "*", 2)
df
#    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# 1     2   22   21   31
# 2     4   24   22   32
# 3     6   26   23   33
# 4     8   28   24   34
# 5    10   30   25   35
# 6    12   32   26   36
# 7    14   34   27   37
# 8    16   36   28   38
# 9    18   38   29   39
# 10   20   40   30   40
```